# iOS - pass data to another view controller

Tags: ios, segue

i have two view controllers, lets call them firstViewController and secondViewController. they are linked from firstViewController to secondViewController using segue in storyboard. the storyboard segue properties are:

identifier: showSecondViewController
style: moda

firstViewController contains collectionViews of product items and a label showing the total number of items in shopping cart. When a collectionView item is clicked, it will open up secondViewController. on secondViewController, i click add button to add items into shopping cart. when this happens, i wanna update the label showing the total number of items in shopping cart in firstViewController.

how shall i do this? should i create another segue between secondVieController and firstViewController?

i tried the following but am getting error: `No visible @interface for "secondViewController declares the selector 'pushViewController:animated'`

```
-(IBAction)addToCart:(id)sender
{
......
    firstViewController *fvc = [[firstViewController alloc] init];
    fvc.badge.value = _shoppingItems.count;
    [self pushViewController:fvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did you include the .h file for firstViewController, and where is pushViewController declared?

Comment: hi, in secondViewController.h, i have #import "firstViewController.h"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should familiarise yourself with the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architectural pattern as this is the most commonly used pattern in user-interactive applications.  You have your views, which are in your storyboard, your controllers (`UIViewController` subclasses), what you are probably missing is your *model* - This is a class that stores and manages the data - in your case this is your shopping cart.

I would suggest that you create a ShoppingCart class and implement it as a [singleton](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) that way any of your view controllers can easily get a reference to it.

As far as returning to your first view controller from your second, you can use an unwind segue - See the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732499/how-to-dismiss-a-modal-that-was-presented-in-a-uistoryboard-with-a-modal-segue), not the accepted answer.

The code in your question is attempting to present a *new* instance of view controller 1 - which, if it worked, would result in a deeper and deeper series of views as your app was used.

Comment: hi thank you for the reply. i tired this method and it works. i am using mySaveUnwindSegueCallback

Answer (score 0):

According to code your code, you are calling `pushViewController:animated:` on `self` in `-(IBAction)addToCart:(id)sender`. But `pushViewController:animated:` is method of `UINavigationController` not `UIViewController`. So you should change your function as below.

```
-(IBAction)addToCart:(id)sender
{
......
    firstViewController *fvc = [[firstViewController alloc] init];
    fvc.badge.value = _shoppingItems.count;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to return from a modal segue

Comment: I know he is creating new instance of firstViewController and setting its value. But here I gave answer regarding his error and not regarding application architecture.

Comment: hi, this method works too. however im going for paulW11 answer because  its much cleaner. however, thank you too